# listbox null after a post

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

with spring 3.0

when i click to submit information (post) this method is called here

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String userResult(@ModelAttribute UserForm userForm, Model model) {

    List<UserInfo> listUserInfo = userService.searchUserInfo(userForm.getsearchCriteria());
    userForm.setListUserInfo(listUserInfo);
    userForm.setSearchDone(true);
    model.addAttribute(userForm);

    return "userSearch";
}
```

the jsp have many listbox, when i check the userForm and model, 
all listbox is null... 
is there a way to avoid that? because i will need to do some call to db every time

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @ModelAttribute in a controller method in this way.

```
public class YourController{
    @ModelAttribute("list1")
    public List<YourObject> retrieveList1(){
         //retrieve here the list from database
         return list1;
    }

    public String userResult(@ModelAttribute UserForm userForm, Model model) {
        ...
    }
}
```

When you annotate the method with @ModelAttribute("list1") then this method will automatically be executed before any method in the controller and then the result will be added in the model at "list1". You can set list1 to the value property you need and add as many @ModelAttribute annotated controllers as you need.

Comment: i tried your solution, the list is ok in the model... but does we suppose to use the model in the jsp?

Comment: @user660503 I don't really understand your comment. If you want to use that list in the JSP you just have to use the name you have used in the @ModelAttibute annotation. For example list1 in the example. For example in a select it would be <form:select path="item" items="${list1}"/>